# NodeJs Async/Await not executing properly

Tags: node.js, async-await

Here is a simple example of my code (index.js)

```js
function sleep() {
    return new Promise(() =>setTimeout(function(){console.log("In promise")}, 2000));
}

async function execute() {
    console.log("Start");
    await sleep();
    console.log("End");
}

execute();
```

When I run this code with
`node index.js`, the result is

```
Start
In promise
```

Why is that ?

Shouldn't "End" be also written in the logs ?

Comment: The promise is never resolved (or rejected, for that matter), so it's unclear why you'd expect to get to `End`.

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>setTimeout(function(){console.log("In promise")resolve()}, 2000));` Add resolve

Answer (score 4):

You are not resolving the promise. Also your console log should not be placed there:

```js
function sleep() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log("In promise")
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve()
      }, 2000);
    })
}

async function execute() {
    console.log("Start");
    await sleep();
    console.log("End");
}

execute();
```

Comment: Correct! Thanks everybody for fast responses.